# Como obtener email de usuario por id?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

soy nuevo en esto. Resulta que tengo una aplicación que debe enviar un correo a los usuarios que se muestran en la vista. [image: Vista de ofertas]

Esta es la vista que, mediante el id de la oferta, me muestra los usuarios. Tengo un controlador que, ya con una estructura, me envía un correo:

```
public JsonResult SendMailToUser()
    {


        bool result = false;

        result = SendEmail("Correo@correo.com", "Test", "<p>Hi abc,<br/>This message is for testing purpose. So don't be upset.<br/>Kind Regards,<br/>abc</p>");
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public bool SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string emailBody)
    {
        try
        {
            string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString();
            string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"].ToString();

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody);
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;

            client.Send(mailMessage);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Como puedo obtener el el correo del usuario mediante el id, y luego enviar el correo?.

En si, el controlador funciona, pero con un correo dado, y lo que necesito es que mediante el click "Enviar correo", mande un correo a ese usuario.

```
<div id="content body" class="dark-mode">
        <hr />

        <h4>En esta sección, puede ver los usuarios que han postulado a la oferta</h4>
        <hr />
        <h4>Lista de usuarios que han postulado:</h4>
        <br />
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label>Email</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Rut</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Nombres</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Apellidos</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Telefono</label>
                </th>
                <th>

                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUsers.Email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUsers.Rut)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUsers.Nombres)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUsers.Apellidos)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUsers.Telefono)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <a class="btn" onclick="SendEmail()">Enviar correo</a>

                    </div>


                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <p>
            <a style="width:200px;color:white;" href="~/OfertaLaboral/Index" class="Button btn btn-danger">Volver al listado</a>

        </p>
    </div>
<script>
var SendEmail = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/OfertaPostulante/SendMailToUser",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    })
   }
</script>
```

Ojalá me puedan ayudar, soy principiante en esto :/

Saludos!

Comment: Creo que he entendido tu duda mejor de lo que te han contestado, así que te contesto 'a grosso modo': Intentaría añadir el parámetro email al evento onclick del tag 'a', algo así como `onclick="SendEmail(@item.AspNetUsers.Email)` (no recuerdo exactamente cómo, pero debería ser algo así, ya que el tag 'a' existe dentro del foreach, el cual tiene conocimiento de cada ítem en cada iteración). Luego sólo tendrías que usarlo como parámetro en la llamada ajax, usando `data:` que sería el parámetro a incluir en la llamada a tu url

Answer (score 0):

Te agrego el cuerpo de un metodo para enviar correo.
como puedes ver los datos de cadena los puedes cambiar por parametros,
y la funcion generaCuerpoCorreo puede contener el html que tienes al inicio de tu codigo,
claro que debe ser de tipo string.

```
public void enviarCorreo() {

string deDireccionOrigen = "UniversidadCentral@gmail.com";

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
{
    UserName = deDireccionOrigen,
    Password = "mipasSecreto" 
};

smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
message.From = new MailAddress(deDireccionOrigen);
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(alumno.CorreoElectronico));
message.Subject = "Solicidud de Tramite";
message.IsBodyHtml = true; 
message.Body = GeneraCuerpoCorreo(alumno.NombreCompleto);

//documento adjunto
var docAdjunto = GeneraDocumentoAdjunto(alumno, ObternerConstanciaNombre(tipoDocumentoId));
message.Attachments.Add(docAdjunto);

smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Send(message);

}
```

saludos.

Comment: Genial, le echaré una mirada, muchas gracias !